# how to increment a whole word match in python using a variable in the regex

Tags: python, regex, variables, increment

I am trying to show how many words match in a txt file using python and regex but instead of using the term 'like' I would like to use the variable 'words'

```
text = 'I like and love green grass'
positive_words = positive_words=open("positive.txt").read()

words = text.split(' ')

if re.search(r'\blike\b',positive_words):
    positive_counter=positive_counter+1
print positive_counter
```

in my txt file I have the words 'like' and 'love' so positive_counter should equal 2.. How would I use words as a variable instead of 'like'? This works now but just do not know how to incorporate the variable words

Comment: Do you want to search positive_words present in text or the other way around ? As it is written, you are looking for `like` inside `positive_words`, and not inside `words`

Comment: Why are you assigning twice to `positive_words`?

Comment: yes I am trying to use the words in 'text' to match words in positive_words

Comment: Make a regex out of `positive words`, then search your string using that regex. Works better that way. Use this [tool](http://www.regexformat.com/version_files/Rx5_ScrnSht01.jpg) to make the regex. Reduces latency by %99.99.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
text = 'I like and love green grass'
positive_words = positive_words=open("positive.txt").read()

words = text.split(' ')

for word in words:
    if re.search(r'\b' + word + r'\b',positive_words):
        positive_counter=positive_counter+1
print positive_counter
```

Just looping all of the words in text.

Answer (score 1):

From the regex point of view, this should work:

```
re.search(r'\b(I|like|and|love|green|grass)\b', positive_words)
```

To build the re from your text variable (note, I'm coding this from memory, you may need to tweak it somewhat):

```
regex = r'\b(%s)\b' % "|".join(words)
re.search(regex, positive_words)
```

Comment: then you need to increment positive counter by one for each match

Comment: Indeed, but looks like the OP is smart enough to figure that out; I'm just proposing a way out, not coding an entire solution :)